# cron.hourly job not running

Tags: ubuntu, cron

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I've looked at a lot of different articles and threads, and I still can't get my `cron.hourly` jobs to run automatically. I am trying to run a backup on my PostgreSQL database. In `/etc/cron.hourly`, I have only one script named `pg_backup`. Here are the permissions on it:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1543 Oct 16 19:07 pg_backup
```

If I run `run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly`, the output is as follows:

> /etc/cron.hourly//pg_backup

That looks good. If I run the script using `run-parts` manually, it works as expected and backs up my database. Here's the command I'm using:

`run-parts -v --report /etc/cron.hourly`

That's great, but for whatever reason, it's not running every hour by itself. I really don't know what could be wrong. I've checked all the logs and haven't been able to find any error messages.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that my `/etc/crontab` file has the shell specified like so: `SHELL=/bin/sh`. My script runs in bash. Is it sufficient to have the shebang at the top of my script for it to use bash? `#!/bin/bash`

**UPDATE 2**

As suggested by Broco, I put the job in my crontab, and it's still not working. Here's what I did:

`sudo crontab -e`

Then I added the following to the file:

`* * * * * root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup`

I made it run every minute to get quicker feedback on whether or not it's running, and it seems to be running but isn't actually performing the backup.

Here's part of my syslog. I used the command `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 17 14:02:01 User CRON[63871]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup)
Oct 17 14:02:01 User CRON[63870]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 17 14:03:01 User CRON[63917]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup)
Oct 17 14:03:01 User CRON[63916]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 17 14:04:01 User CRON[63966]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup)
Oct 17 14:04:01 User CRON[63965]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 17 14:05:01 User CRON[64013]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup)
Oct 17 14:05:01 User CRON[64012]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 17 14:05:01 User CRON[64014]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Oct 17 14:06:01 User CRON[64060]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup)
Oct 17 14:06:01 User CRON[64059]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 17 14:07:01 User CRON[64106]: (root) CMD (root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup)
Oct 17 14:07:01 User CRON[64105]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: just out of curiousity, what time does cron.hourly do its job on your system? it is not necessarly at exactly on the hour, for example my system is on minute 17.   you can check it out in /etc/crontab

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Mine is on minute 17 as well. I've waited a few hours without any luck.

Comment: Can you show the output of `/var/log/cron.log` or similar files?

Comment: Does it work if you put the file directly into /etc/crontab? E.g. `0 * * * * root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup`

Comment: @shodanshok @Broco Thanks for the questions! I've updated my question with that information. It doesn't seem to be working even with putting the script in my `crontab`.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. It's related to the paths I'm using in my scripts. I'll update this thread later; I need to head out now.

Comment: Be careful that, as shown by the logs, you are executing your script **each minute** This behavior is probably due to the `* * * * * root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup` line added to your crontab. Consider removing it or substituting it with `01 * * * * root /etc/cron.hourly/pg_backup` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron job *is* running, but the job is having a problem.

You normally should get an email with the output (and errors!) but you do not get email because:

```
Oct 17 14:02:01 User CRON[63870]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

You don't have anything installed on your system that is capable of sending mail. Thus, the output is thrown away.

Consider [installing an MTA](https://askubuntu.com/q/536766/75668) so that you can have the output emailed to you and then find out what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! As Michael Hampton pointed out, my job was running, but it had some errors. I didn't have an MTA installed, so I installed `postfix` with `sudo apt-get install postfix`. After doing so, I was able to look at the `/var/mail/root` file to see error messages related to my `cron` jobs.

My main issue ended up being related to missing environment variables. Since `cron` runs on `root`, my environment variables weren't set whenever the script ran. So, I included my `.bashrc` at the top of my script like this:

`source "$HOME/.bashrc"`

In my `root` user's `.bashrc`, I added the environment variables that I needed for the script. That still didn't work, though; the environment variables still weren't being set when the script ran. To fix this, I added to my script the following line before the line that includes `.bashrc`:

`export PS1="1"`

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557777/crontab-job-does-not-get-the-environment-variables-set-in-bashrc-file/15574078#15574078), this environment variable prevents `.bashrc` from loading in non-interactive sessions, so when it is set, `.bashrc` will load.

Thanks a lot for the help, everyone!